# Javascript setInterval not firing while async ajax calls waiting for completion

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome, setinterval

Environment is asp.net 4.0, C#, Chrome + Chrome debugger

When the user clicks on a button, it fires four ajax requests. The first is synchronous. The second and third are asynchronous - they (hopefully) run in parallel. The final call cannot start until calls two and three complete. While all of this is happening, I want to update a dialog box with a "." every second on both the second and third jobs.

I am trying to accomplish this with an ajax call that runs every second and asks a webservice to check on the status which is recorded as an object in session. I am using setInterval to perform the periodic check:

```
var checkTimer = setInterval(checkProgress, 1000);

function checkProgress() {
    var progress = ajaxCall("WebServices/FLSAService.asmx/CheckFLSASaveStatus");

    if (progress.job1.complete && progress.job2.complete) {
        clearInterval(checkTimer);
)
```

Unfortunately there are two problems:

1) the ajax call doesn't happen until both jobs one and two are completed unless I put a breakpoint in the chrome debugger. It fires just fine then, but checkProgress doesn't get fired
2) If I run with no breakpoints in Chrome, the diaglog box remains hidden until both jobs two and three are completed.

Comment: Can you put this code in the context of the rest of your code? How is it all structured? From what you have here, I don't see a problem.

Comment: What is `ajaxCall`, it's probably ASYNC, so you timer will never be cleared since `progress` will sit at `undefined`

Comment: You don't need another ajax call to check if the other two are completed, just set some flags when each dependent ajax callback is invoked.

Comment: We would need to see the code for the `ajaxCall()` function.  If it is synchronous, then you are correct that nothing else will run while it is waiting for completion.  If it is asynchronous, then it will return  immediately.  Neither will work with your current code.

Comment: honestly I would set a flag that both ajax calls can see, then in your completion method check to see if the flag is set, if not set to true, otherwise call the method that starts the 4th ajax call.

Comment: The call to checkProgress is made from a setTimeout (tried setInterval too) and it happens before any async calls are made. The call shown above is synchronous and thus blocking. It starts competing with two async calls, all calling the same webservice. The problem may have to do with multiple requests coming from the same source, one sync and the other two sync. And please remember that the purpose of checkProgress is so that I can update the screen and keep the user informed.